# PhoneApplicationFrame in PhoneApplicationPage

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, master-pages, frame

I have a awkward problem about Windows Phone 8 Page Structure.
I want to use some structure like on website which name is MasterPage so 
I have a Page for MasterPage, and i want to put a frame for contents.
But when i try to do that, i got an error which is 
**"Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object"**

xaml code is below.
thanks for your helping.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage x:Class="Teknosa.Phone.Views.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:ignore="http://www.ignore.com"
    xmlns:manager="clr-namespace:Teknosa.Phone.Managers"
    mc:Ignorable="d ignore"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait"
    Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">


    <!--Frame contains the root where all other page content is placed-->
    <phone:PhoneApplicationFrame x:Name="ContentFrame" >

    </phone:PhoneApplicationFrame>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put an application frame inside another application frame. In fact you can only have one `PhoneApplicationFrame` in your application. The setup your code has will cause an infinite nesting condition. The `PhoneApplicationFrame` hosts a `PhoneApplicationPage` which hosts the `PhoneApplicationFrame` and so on. This continues infinitely, and is the reason you aren't allowed to do this.

If you're just trying to navigate to a web page, you can use the phone's built in web browser.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage x:Class="Teknosa.Phone.Views.MainPage"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
   xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
   xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
   xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
   xmlns:ignore="http://www.ignore.com"
   xmlns:manager="clr-namespace:Teknosa.Phone.Managers"
   mc:Ignorable="d ignore"
   FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
   FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
   Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
   SupportedOrientations="Portrait"
   Orientation="Portrait"
   shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">
    <Grid>
        <phone:WebBrowser Source="<URL or binding>"/>
    </Grid>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```